# What is this query string parameter: _sm_au_

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine

My app engine site redirects links to the site index page to the same URL with this query string appended: ?_sm_au_=iFVtD2FW4H4wSHS6.

It only seems to happen in Chrome. Other browsers do not get redirected.

I'm using the default App Engine Java framework. I'm not sure if the query string is coming from App Engine or from Chrome. I have been unable to find any documentation on `_sm_au_`.

Comment: That query string is usually related to Google AdWords cookies. It is used for retargeting ads. If you're not explicitly using AdWords in your project, you might have an ad-injecting Chrome extension installed. Double check it!

Comment: Thanks, repost this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That query string is usually related to Google AdWords cookies. It is used for retargeting ads.

If you're not explicitly using AdWords in your project, you might have an ad-injecting Chrome extension installed. You may double check the latter by accessing your app/website from an incognito window.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer says, advertisement-injecting extension.  I just want to add that on 24 December 2019 I got 50+ megabytes of traffic over 331 hits within 51 seconds from an IP address owned by "ZScaler Inc", all appearing to be Chrome 79 on Windows 10 repeatedly downloading the same page (including images) with `_sm_au_` query strings added (and the genuine version of my site does not carry advertising, so it must have been an injector).  Since I'd rather not see my server be brought down by that kind of thing happening more often in future, I set Apache's `.htaccess` as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_sm_au_=.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /you-have-adware.txt? [PT]
```

where `you-have-adware.txt` contains a short message to explain the situation to them (in text rather than HTML to minimise the chances of the plugin being able to further manipulate it), and a suggestion to try Incognito mode, or upgrade to GNU/Linux.

Comment: Regrettably, some workplaces are now outsourcing their MITM web monitoring to ZScaler. I arrived at this thread because I saw these parameters being injected into links I was following **from a Word document I was making**. (And, "ZScaler aside", I'm reasonably confident this machine has no malware on it...)

Comment: OK I've now sent an enquiry to ZScaler via their web form (I set type to "Press enquiry" because this is a public discussion) in the hope that they might be able to explain why they're adding these parameters.  Maybe on 24 December somebody went silly and hammered the Refresh button multiple times per second for a whole minute on a work PC running ZScaler with my website on the screen (in which case I hope that person is OK); this still seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this query string comes from a visitor's Zscaler ZIA enterprise proxy and has nothing to do with AdWords, advertisements, or malware. The likely reason why @silas-s-brown was seeing a lot of requests from a "ZScaler Inc" IP is that one or more people were visiting Silas's site using their employer's network. Zscaler offers a cloud-hosted enterprise proxy service, so one IP could be shared by any number of Zscaler tenants (i.e. corporate entities subscribing to the proxy service).

ZIA has a feature where it allows/denies access to internet resources based on whether or not a user has recently authenticated to the proxy. A vague description of this behavior is present on [the About Zscaler Cookies documentation page](https://help.zscaler.com/zia/about-zscaler-cookies). When a user visits a page in their browser, ZIA appends an `_sm_au_` query string to resource URLs (through a series of HTTP `307` redirects) to track what user is accessing a file. During these redirects, ZIA also sets various cookies such as `ssm_au_c` and `ssm_au_d` on the domain of the resource, and `_sm_au_c` and `_sm_au_d` on the `zscalertwo.net` domain. This seems to be for similar reasons. Here's an example HTTP request sequence for a 3rd-party script file embedded in a page on my site (I captured the sequence from a user's browser that was behind a ZIA proxy):

[image: example HTTP request sequence]

P.S. if you know who visits your site, you can [use this procedure to determine if they are behind a Zscaler proxy](https://help.zscaler.com/zia/verifying-users-traffic-being-forwarded-zscaler-service).