# How do I prevent my localhost port from changing while debugging when launching in IIS Express with SpaServices and Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, windows-11, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have a visual studio solution for an ASP.NET Core application. This ASP.NET Core application also uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices to render a React SPA. On some PCs, it runs as expected: when launching it in debug mode through visual studio, it loads up on the configured address and port (localhost:3000).

I recently upgraded to Windows 11. Ever since after that, when I try to run the project, visual studio will fire up a web browser, load the app on the configured port (localhost:3000), then switch to a random port! (in the 50000+ range). Note that the same project, on the same version in git, launches as expected (loads and stays on localhost:3000) on other PCs running Windows 10.

Additionally, I can run other applications, like a react frontend on port 3000 at a separate time with no incident.

launchsettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        }
    }
}
```

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581160/how-to-keep-visual-studio-or-docker-from-changing-the-host-port-numbers), but this was for docker only. I'm not using docker for this test, just IIS Express.

IIS Express's tray icon even shows it running on port 3000:

[image: IIS Running on Port 3000]

When I turn on tracing, I can see that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices` reports a new, random port number as the port to serve the application from:

```
2022-12-23 10:19:32.1515|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices|You can now view myapp.name in the browser.
2022-12-23 10:19:32.1515|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices|  Local:            http://localhost:52371
2022-12-23 10:19:32.1515|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices|  On Your Network:  http://10.11.12.13:52371
```

(names and IP addresses anonymized.)

Why visual studio / IIS express changing this port number on load, and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Just a small hint, (I used to configure WCF services this way)
if you open project properties, in solution explorer and go to the web tab, you would find under the Servers section the IIS express project URL, normally, the associated port goes within the 50000 range...

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, is it possible some other process is using port 3000 and this is causing the site to redirect to another port. Though I thought an error would be generated if the port was already being used. Also, what version of VS are you using, VS2022?

Comment: could you pls try to run visual studio with admin ?

Comment: @quaabaam - I can launch other apps on port 3000. In fact, when I launch the ASP.NET Core app, it *responds* to port 3000, then redirects to this random alternate port!

Comment: @TinyWang - Running with admin has the same outcome: the page initially loads to port 3000, then reloads to a random other port in the 50000+ range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me ended up being related to zscalar's proxy behind the corporate firewall. I needed to ensure that localhost **and** 127.0.0.1 were added to the `NO_PROXY` environment variable.

The string `"_sm_au_"` being appended to the URL (like `localhost:56912/?_sm_au_=123vAB12AB842t12`" ) was a sign that zscalar was involved, as I found originally here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72735926/18097