# Why is the localhost ssl port number is different with react webpack error port number>

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, nodes

I use visual studio 2016 template asp core react template to create a project. When I run it, it display the react project at url `https://localhost:5001/`, I check underneath javascript error, it has:

> WebSocket connection to wss://localhost:54082/ws failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

Where does port number `54082` come from?

Here is my `launchsetting.json`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8351",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyReact": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to change

```
 "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8351",
      "sslPort": 0 // change original 44354 to 0
    }
```

I also add this to `.env` file `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`, it still display the same error.

My machine has Node `v12.19.0`, I am not permitted to upgrade it.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74892889/how-do-i-prevent-my-localhost-port-from-changing-while-debugging-when-launching): I am using window 10, Yes, I have zscalar behind corporate firewall, I am not permitted to change Environment Variable in my PC.
Update:
But I was able to add NO_PROXY :localhost, 127.0.0.1 by adding it at the project solution property. I don't have http and https "launch browser" choices. If I uncheck "launch browser", my browser will not show up.
The .vscode folder is under nodes_modules' different folders, its settings.json doesn't contain any url information.
@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans : thank you. I installed webpack. I think it is from WebSocketClient.js . I tried to traced it, but don't know how, managed to find the url is from dynamic generated code file bundle.js :

```
__webpack_require__("./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=51359&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10");
```

but don't know how this url value is formulated.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where's the code that actually creates the websocket on the client-side?

Comment: What is in the `launch.json` file inside the `.vscode` folder?

Comment: The wss running on that port is likely used for Hot Module Reload or your Debug configuration. Re-validate Step 2 from this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022#set-the-project-properties

Comment: @Lynda don't show code in comments: [edit] your post to [include the missing information](/help/how-to-ask), with proper formatting and details, something that can't be done in a comment.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: When I edit, it says comments is only for 5 minutes. I don't know how to edit it.

Comment: Don't edit your comment: [edit] your post (that link is a direct link to the post edit view), and copy-paste the information from your comment (not literally the comment) and integrate it into your post (i.e. add text as necessary, and properly format any code). Then you can delete your comments and instead leave one that says you updated your post with the missing information.